# Java regex replace

Tags: java, regex

I've a csv string like

```
"abc, java, stackoverflow  ,     stack exchange   , test"
```

Can I use regex to remove the space around the commas to get a string like

```
"abc,java,stackoverflow,stack exchange,test"
```

Comment: What about `a , "b , b" , c`?

Comment: Unfortunately "b , b" will be treated as two different values, but i'm fine with that :)

Comment: okay, then Chris' solution will do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ",");
```

Comment: @Rnet: `\s` (which has to be written as `\\s` in a Java string literal) matches one whitespace character. `*` matches zero or more of the "thing" before it. So, `\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters. You can figure out the rest. ;-)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: Thank you:)

Comment: +1 Damn. I was thinking why `replace()` is not working. Now I see from the docs, that `replaceAll()` supports regex. Thanks!

Comment: @asgs: if you had used replace() to replace the white space, it would have replaced the space between the values also.

Comment: @Rnet actually, i was using the same regex inside the `replace()`.